# PySpark dataframe contains header of CSV after load

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I read csv files with a Synapse Notebook (Spark Pool has min. 3 Nodes). Header option is set to true, but my Data frame contains still a few rows with headers. That I realize it, that not every file contain headers. There are only three headers of 9 files. I have already checked, that these files do not include the header twice. Is there any idea?

```
df = spark.read.option("header", True).option("escape", "\"").csv(f"abfss://stage@costmgmt.dfs.core.windows.net/latest_export_file/{billing_year}/{billing_month}/*.csv")
```

Maybe to describe the input and output more in detail.

I have 9 different csv files with the same column structure.

```
abfss://stage@costmgmt.dfs.core.windows.net/latest_export_file/{billing_year}/{billing_month}/file-1.csv
abfss://stage@costmgmt.dfs.core.windows.net/latest_export_file/{billing_year}/{billing_month}/file-2.csv
abfss://stage@costmgmt.dfs.core.windows.net/latest_export_file/{billing_year}/{billing_month}/file-3.csv
abfss://stage@costmgmt.dfs.core.windows.net/latest_export_file/{billing_year}/{billing_month}/file-n.csv
```

The files have the following structure:

```
SubscriptionID,SubscriptionName,ResourceGroup,ResourceName,Price
c7b7978a-6e5a-11ee-b962-0242ac120002,Subscription 1,ResourceGroup A,453.45
...
```

When I now run this code

```
df_check = df.withColumn("filename", input_file_name()) \
             .groupBy("filename", "SubscriptionName") \
             .count()
display(df_check)
```

I get this output:

```
| filename   | SubscriptionName | count() |
|------------|------------------|---------|
| file-1.csv | Subscription 1   | 234.345 |
| file-2.csv | Subscription 2   |  34.345 |
| file-3.csv | Subscription 3   | 134.325 |
| file-3.csv | SubscriptionName |       1 |
| file-4.csv | Subscription 4   |  44.287 |
| file-5.csv | Subscription 5   | 133.255 |
| file-6.csv | Subscription 6   |     332 |
| file-7.csv | Subscription 7   |  44.287 |
| file-7.csv | SubscriptionName |       1 |
| file-8.csv | Subscription 8   | 133.255 |
| file-9.csv | Subscription 9   |     332 |
| file-9.csv | SubscriptionName |       1 |
```

What you can see from my understanding is, that there is in a few (not in all) parsed files the header line is part of the dataframe.

Any idea why?

BR Gerrit

Comment: Shouldn't you put `.option("header", "true")`?

Comment: @partlov - they're the same for spark.

Comment: what is your expected output?And what output you are getting currently?

Comment: @Gerrit If I understand correctly you want to load a bunch of CSV files and some of them have header, while others don't?

Comment: @partlov yes, you are right. Most of theses files the header is skipped correctly and used a columns name of my dataframe. But for three files the headline is parsed as normal data and contained in my dataframe.

Comment: I don't think there is out of the box way to do that but to find out which CSVs are with header and which are without, load them with into two data frames and do union. Let's see if somebody has any other suggestion.

Comment: All of these files do have the header line. But in some files Spark is skipping them (as expected) and in some files not. I try now to understand why the header is sometimes *not* skipped.

Comment: header is checked at first line of the file. If it is empty it is skipped and continues for next line to load. check any of your file having empty line at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below approach.

First, get the schema by read any one file which is having header.

```
schema = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("escape", "\"").csv(f"dbfs:/samp/file_with_header1.csv").schema
schema.fieldNames()
```

[image]

Next, read all files without header, that is `header=false`
and filter the rows having headers.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = spark.read.schema(schema).option("header", "false").option("escape", "\"").csv(f"dbfs:/samp/*.csv")
display(df.filter(~col(df.columns[0]).isin(schema.fieldNames())))
```

[image]

Comment: I added an example what really occurs if I load that data

Comment: All of your 9 files have header right? And none of the file is having header twice ?

Comment: yes, you're right